# Subquery in Rails 5 to get Minimum of Limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I wrote the following query:

```
Value.where('date <= ?', date).where('symbol = ?', symbol).order(date: :desc).limit(20).average(:min)
```

So I want to get all values with the given conditions, get the latest 20 of them and calculate the average.

What happens is that the limit gets ignored by the average method. I already understood why and learned that I need to build a subquery.

But what I have tried so far does not work. Can anybody help?

Comment: Where is your code for the sub query that you mention? The only code snippet shown does not include a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

did u try like following? without any subqueries

```
vals = Value.where('date <= ?', date).where('symbol = ?', symbol).order(date: :desc).limit(20).to_a
avg = (vals.size>0) ? vals.sum(&:min)/vals.size : 0
```